# Where can I get this iPad stand?

Tags: ipad

I am not sure if my question is okay to post or not.

I found a cheap, but simple and beautiful iPad stand on a korean website.

http://www.funshop.co.kr/vs/detail.aspx?categoryno=1359&itemno=10516

[image: wire frame ipad stand]

description says that it is from USA.

I googled with its name 'easy ipad stand', but I could not find anything.

anyone knows where to buy this product?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not an iPad stand—it's just a cheap three wire display stand. It's the kind of stand that can display anything at all, which could include an iPad, I guess (although I'd want something a little more secure, personally). You should be able to get one at your local office supply store for $2-5.

[Here they are on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RL9JHC) at two for $5.65.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but from what it looks like the product is only available from this website. My only suggestions would be trawl eBay, or try and translate the page using google translate? Sorry I can't help anymore, but someone else may have found something?